# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to type int

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I am attempting an INSERT statement with a nested SELECT statement.  Both of the database fields are of `int` type.

My statement:

```
energy_command = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO energy ([ApplicationID], [usage], [policy], [audit], [lighting], [over_lighting], [controls], [turn_off], [energy_star], [weatherize],[thermostat], [natural_light], [air], [renewable_assessment], [on_site_renewable], [HVAC],[renewable_power], [efficient_enroll], [efficient_attain], [other]) " & 
"VALUES ('(SELECT ApplicationID FROM general where Business_Name = """ & txtName.Text & """)', '" & track_usage & "', '" & develop_strategy & "', '" & perform_audit & "', '" & replace_bulbs & "', '" & reduce_lighting & "', '" & lighting_controls & "', '" & not_in_use_policy & "', '" & energy_star & "', '" & weatherize & "', '" & program_thermo & "', '" & natural_light & "', '" & air_quality & "', '" & site_assessment & "', '" & renewable_power & "', '" & HVAC & "', '" & renewable_energy & "', '" & energy_programs & "', '" & energy_certification & "', '" & energy_other & "')", connection)`
```

My error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value '(SELECT ApplicationID FROM general where
>   Business_Name = "a")' to data type int.

My only thought is that it's trying to insert the entire `SELECT` statement into the `INT` field.  Am I wrong?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you put a single quote to quote the query, so it is considered as a string. You should remove the single quote of your query just this

```
VALUES ((SELECT ApplicationID FROM general where Business_Name = "'" & txtName.Text & "'"), ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the apostrophes around the query.

Change:

```
'(SELECT ApplicationID FROM general where Business_Name = """ & txtName.Text & """)'
```

to:

```
(SELECT ApplicationID FROM general where Business_Name = """ & txtName.Text & """)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also: if you want to insert data into a table based on a `SELECT` from another table, you need to **not** use the `VALUES` keyword, but instead use this style:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTargetTable(Co1, Col2, ..., ColN)
   SELECT
      Src1, Src2, ...., SrcN
   FROM  
      dbo.YourSourceTableHere
   WHERE
      YourConditionHere
```

No `VALUES` needed....